# Will Application Transport Security be turned-OFF for apps build for iOS 8 or lower?

Tags: ios, app-transport-security

If a user has an iPad running my app on iOS 8.4, will ATS be enforced or turned-off by default when the user upgrades to iOS 9? I could not find any official documentation on this behavior. Any referenced would help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apps build for SDKs lower than iOS 9 opt-out of ATS by default.

ref: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14376

Comment: That does not align with what we experienced with all beta versions released so far...

Comment: Not sure about your scenario, but I was able to verify this using a simple app package built for iOS 8 on iOS 9 and it just worked. When building the same app from source for iOS 9, ATS engaged and http requests were blocked . My device is on iOS 9 beta 5.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Apps build with iOS 8 SDK or lower will not be effected by ATS.

Answer (score -1):

ATS is a feature introduced with iOS 9 and is enforced by the OS and not your app. Running your app on iOS 8 would not cause any issue ATS related. ATS is evaluated only on iOS 9 (and up, i assume).

Comment: Thanks. But my actual question is if ATS would be enforced on an app-targeting-iOS-8 and running on OS iOS 9.

Comment: Yes it would. The target wouldn't matter for the App as it runs on iOS 9.

Comment: Interesting. So does that mean thousands of apps, say - that perform insecure http loads, would break when users  upgrade their apple devices to iOS 9 ? 

This link suggests that apps developed for iOS 8 "won't opt into" ATS: (http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/apple-tightens-security-with-app-transport-security--cms-24420).

Comment: Yes, those apps will break. I work in mobile software development company and we have seen apps break for exactly that reason. That is why Apple is giving everyone a heads-up for the last couple of month so you can prepare updates prior to the release of iOS 9. Also, if you follow coding best practices your apps won't break because you secured your traffic anyways...

Comment: In Apple-dev-forum, an apple-staff confirmed that apps targeting lower sdk's will not be affected by ATS link: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14376